# Search for specific string in multiple excel files

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to python, so bear with me on this one.
I want to make a script that searches within all excel files in a specific folder, to see if they contain an '@' sign. If it finds a match it should write to a log.txt files with the name of the excel file. I don't have the name of the excel files in advance.

So far I'm stuck at just read in one file, and return true if it finds the string. What I got is

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(open('test.xlsx','rb'), sheetname=0)
print(df)

if '@' in df:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

This returns the content of sheet1 in the excel file correctly, but the search to find a match, doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Maybe Im doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read through [Pandas - Working with Text Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) specifically the section on strings that match or contain a pattern.

Unfortunately you cannot search a DataFrame with the string methods common to core Python. Instead you would use a StringMethod, like so:

```
out = False
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].str.contains('@').any():
        out = 'True'
        break
print(out)
```

Also, I don't believe it is necessary to use `open` when using [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). E.g

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('test.xlsx','rb'), sheetname=0)
```

Can be rewritten:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheetname=0)
```

As far as iterating over files in a folder take a look at the builtin module [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Answer (score 1):

This an answer without using pandas

```
import logging

LOG_FILENAME = r'file_output_location_path\log.txt'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                    level=logging.WARNING,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s'
                    )


source_folder = r'excel_file_folder_path'

def containsString():
    for somefile in os.listdir(source_folder):
        if'@' in somefile:
            logging.warning(somefile)
```

Comment: Beginner questions: what the r' stand do? and 'excel_file_folder_path' should that be './foldername'?

Comment: Dosnt seems like this is working, it can find the files, but it dosnt find any @'s when the xlsx file contains it.